# how SAS create an external report(.xlsx file) with filter summation

Tags: sas, xlsx

I have a data for sales in 3 months (sale1, sale2 and sale3), and I need to show the the different summations with different filters.

```
data sales;
 input area load $ prod : $ sale1 sale2 sale3;
  diff=sale3-sale2;
 datalines;
 1 Y p1   109 117 138 
 1 N p1   23  29  20 
 1 Y p2   78  70  68
 1 N p2   63  19  22 
 2 Y p1   49  36  32 
 2 N p1   50  39  44  
 2 Y p3   138 157 158 
 2 N p3   110 126 107 
 3 Y p2   251 267 259  
 3 N p2   182 184 160 
 ;
 run;

ods excel close;
 ods excel file="/C:/data/t1.xlsx"
  options (sheet_name="tab1" frozen_headers='3' frozen_rowheaders='2'       
        embedded_footnotes='yes' autofilter='1-8'); 
 proc report data=sales  nocenter;    
  column area load prod sale1 sale2 sale3 diff change;
  define area -- diff/ display; 
  define sale1-- diff / analysis sum format=comma12. style(column)=[cellwidth=.5in];
 define change / computed format=percent8.2 '% change' style(column)=[cellwidth=.8in];

 compute change;
 change = diff.sum/sale2.sum;
  if change >= 0.1 then call define ("change",'STYLE','STYLE=[color=red 
   fontweight=bold]');
  if change <= -0.1 then call define ("change",'STYLE','STYLE=[color=blue 
   fontweight=bold]');
 endcomp;

  rbreak after / summarize style=[background=lightblue font_weight=bold];
  run;
 ods excel close;
```

this report with no filtering looks like[original report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQJv1.png)
but if I filter with column load='Y' in the .xlsx file, i want to see the result like this:
[output with filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9Z7o.png)
wonder if anyone can help, thanks!

Comment: How would you do this in Excel, without SAS? You can include the code for a function inside SAS instead of prefixed values so if there's a way to do it in Excel, then you can likely do it via SAS with the formula.

Comment: Hi Reeza, what I thought is adding lines of SAS code (excel formula). once the excel files is created, open the excel file and do the filtering, and the sub-total will change according to different filter groups.   My question is what is the formula and how to add the formula, thanks!

Comment: Well that's more of an Excel issue so perhaps find the Excel solution first and then it's trivial to apply in SAS.

Comment: If I was building this, instead of the shown structure, I would build a pivot table report/display instead and then use SAS to refresh the source data in a separate sheet instead.

Comment: this kind of report is recurring weekly, so it is better to let SAS do everything.

Comment: SAS will do everything, just your display approach changes. The Pivot table approach offers more flexibility in the display and just an initial set up for the template.

Comment: I am not familiar with pivot, and wonder if the template  is set up in the SAS,  or after the excel file report is created then to set up the template.